# Problem trying to graphically represent a 2D vector given angle and intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm very new to physics so forgive me if it's a trivial question, but it's something I have trouble figuring out.

I'm trying to solve an exercise, and the exercise says that we're given

$|\overrightarrow{v}| = 2.8 N$, where the vector and the $x$ axis form an angle of $45$ degrees

and $|\overrightarrow{a}| = 2.3 N$, where the vector and the $x$ axis form an angle of $-30$ degrees.

The vectors are supposed to act on a point particle. I'm not sure how to represent this graphically. If we suppose that the point particle is located in (0,0), I tried to do it like this:

[image]

However, I am quite sure that this is not correct but I can't explain why and I'm not sure what would be correct. If the vector $v$ forms an angle of $45$ degrees with the $x$ axis, what would its direction be? Obviously there are two possible ways you can direct the vector, but I'm not sure which one is correct. I'm also not sure about vector $a$ either, but I could maybe figure it out if I figure out vector $v$.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader audience. Note that answers to homework questions with complete solutions may be deleted!

Comment: @Frobenius Hello and thanks for the welcome! Unfortunately, I will have to disagree with your characterization of my question as "homework-like" or "check-my-work", because this was neither my homework (nor anything similar pertaining to it), nor "check-my-work", which I find insulting, as I produced genuine effort to understand something before creating an account and posting here. I'm sure that you meant no ill, but you may want to take a different approach next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The angle of a vector is usually measured from the *positive* x-axis to the vector, with clockwise angles counting as positive. Thus a vector in the same direction as the positive y-axis has an angle of 90 degrees and a vector in the same direction as the negative y-axis has an angle of 270 degrees (or -90 degrees).
2. Vectors representing forces on a particle are best drawn with their tails at the particle instead of their heads. This makes it easier to see geometrically how the vectors add together.
3. The “size” of a force vector is called its magnitude, not its intensity.